# pinyin in google translate API

Tags: scrape

I want to scrape the pinyin off of the googletranslate API instead of having to scrape from some other website (which might change its format in ten thousand ways over time and across different requests).  The JSON that it returns doesn't seem to contain Romanization, although it certainly exists somewhere since it is displayed on the webpage.

I'm using python, but I think that this should be a language independent question.

Suggestions?

Comment: Any result? I am also looking for this answer.

Comment: This seems to cover the same problem as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750093/get-chinese-romanization-from-google-translate-api .. the current answer being that you can not get the romanization through the API.