# Phonetic Characters in Google Translation API

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using the Google Translation API, here is an example request to getting 'Hello' from English to Simplified Chinese:

[Google Translation API - 'Hello' From English to Chinese](https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY_KEY&q=hello&source=en&target=zh-CN&format=text&prettyprint=true)

And as you can see this is pretty much all the data it returns:

> 你好

Which is not very helpful to a user who might want to be able to speak it, so does Google Translation API return any pinyin or phonetic typing so it might return that as:

> Ni Hao

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to remove/change the link such that it does not include your API key.  I know the example doesn't work as well for us if you do, but it probably isn't a good idea to leave it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with the current API. See:

[Get Chinese Romanization from Google Translate API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750093/get-chinese-romanization-from-google-translate-api)

Apparently it is still an open issue that Google has not implemented into the API.

Comment: Thank you and that is very sad to find out!

Comment: It's been 4 years and google is not making this feature still?

Comment: Hell, it's been 8 years now and this is still on the first page of results from Google when looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is finally in beta now.

Check out the docs --> [Google Cloud Translation - Romanize Text](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/romanize-text)