Why Google Translator API is not outputting accurate translation
I am trying to use the google translator API for translating non-english words (transliterated words) to english word. For example, the word "Xingbie" is a Chinese transliterated word which is "Gender" in english word.

Now, when I tried to use the API using I do not get back the translated text.
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate

# Initialize the Translation client
translate_client = translate.Client()

# Function to detect the language of a given text
def detect_language(text):
    result = translate_client.detect_language(text)
    return result['language'], result['confidence']

# Function to translate text
def translate_text(text, target_language):
    translation = translate_client.translate(text, target_language=target_language)
    return translation['translatedText']

# Example usage
text_to_detect = "Xingbie"  # This is a transliterated Chinese word

# Detect language
language, confidence = detect_language(text_to_detect)
print(f"Detected language: {language} (Confidence: {confidence:.2f})")

# Translate to English
translated_text = translate_text(text_to_detect, 'en')
print(f"Translated text: {translated_text}")

Output:
Detected language: zh-Latn (Confidence: 0.94) 
Translated text: Xingbie

The translated text should be "Gender" which is exactly from the browser I can see. However, the API returns the same string. What am I missing here?

I think even though it's detected, pinyin translation is not support by the API. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3535853/609290

Is it only for Chinese word? I tried with a Japanese transliterated word and the API could not translate to english.

They're two different language (representations). I suspect, Translate detects pinyin but doesn't have the full language. I tried added tone markers to the pinyin to see whether that helped but it doesn't appear to do so

Currently, Google Cloud Translation API doesn’t support transliteration for Chinese (zh) words. The API might be recognizing it as Chinese (zh-Latn) but doesn’t inherently understand its meaning.
You can actually monitor the release notes to keep you updated of the recent fixes and announcements. Also, I figured these common issues might be helpful to you.
